# How to map DateRangeField correctly to a Bean in SolrJ?

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I'm asking myself how to map a DateRangeField in Solr's Index to a field in Java.
I'm trying this in Java:

```
@Field("validity_period")
private List<Date> validity_period;
```

And in the schema:

```
<field name="validity_period" type="my_daterangefield" multiValued="true" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
<fieldType name="my_daterangefield" class="solr.DateRangeField" multiValued="true"/>
```

If I index a sample it looks like this in the index:

```
"validity_period":["2018-04-19T22:00:00Z", "2022-09-23T22:00:00Z"],
```

This doesn't look like its correct. Shouldn't it be stored in a format like [from TO to]?

Querying it doesn't work either. For example searching for all documents that are valid today.
Is `List<Date>` really the right data type in java for DateRangeField? I also tried simple `String` and format it into this shape [from TO to] but didn't work.